# Why are these the correct answers for this fill-in-the-blank question?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, clauses

> The nearby air rapidly expands and contracts, [1]**making** the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead [2]**and producing** a tremendous crack.

The options for the bold words in the above text are:

- that makes
- and making
- making
- it makes

And for the second blank

- produces
- is produced by
- and produce
- and producing

The original text had blanks in place of the bold words, but this text has the solutions. Anyone could describe in short detail why these words are the correct answer in this test question?

Comment: It's entirely a matter of opinion *why* someone might choose to replace ***making, producing*** with ***that/which makes, produces***. They mean exactly the same - the only difference is the underlying ***syntax***. Maybe whoever chose the continuous forms did so because they were *told* to use continuous forms, I don't know. It's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: Wow you means it's based on idea? not grammar? it's strange !! this is my exam on some days ago. @FumbleFingers

Comment: Are "That" and "It" capitalized intentionally? If not, neither of those would work in this sentence. They're not **all** based on preference. Some of them are definitely wrong.

Comment: by the way - ***and makes*** is a *particularly* bad stylistic choice (the repetition of ***and*** with a slightly different sense is ugly). But starting a new sentence with ***It makes*** is just another (perfectly valid) stylistic choice. Your "test" strikes me as the work of an amateur who probably doesn't even know English that well himself. He certainly has little understanding of how and when to use multiple-choice-answer tests.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm sure there is a reason behind this option :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Interestingly, this is a case in which I would say **which makes** sounds correct and **that makes** sounds very wrong.  I don't really have the terminology to express why, though.

Comment: @stangdon: I quite agree ***which*** is far better than ***that***. Which is why I included it in my comment even though it wasn't in the original list of options. And also why I don't think the "test-setter" can be a competent native speaker. It seems vanishingly improbable that he intended to test students on their ability to differentiate between ***that*** and ***which***, so I consider that to be an irrelevancy.

Comment: @stangdon As a relative clause, it's non-restrictive by pointing (the comma), function (clausal modifier) and sense; and you can't use *that* with a non-restrictive relative clause.

Answer (score 3):

> The nearby air rapidly expands and contracts, **making** the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead **and producing** a tremendous crack

The given answer is correct because it produces two participle clauses joined by *and*, ***making*** X **and producing** Y; this conjunct construction is a clausal adjunct expressing the result of the expansion and contraction.

HOWEVER—

Two **additional** pairs of choices from the two lists are also semantically and syntactically acceptable:

- > A) The nearby air rapidly expands and contracts, **and making** the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead **produces** a tremendous crack.

  Here we have two coordinated independent clauses: in the second, the gerund clause *making the column vibrate ...* is the subject of the finite verb *produces*.
- > B) The nearby air rapidly expands and contracts, **making** the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead **and produce** a tremendous crack.

  Here the second clause is, like the "correct" answer, a clausal adjunct expressing the result of the expansion and contraction, but it is now a **single** participle clause headed by *making*; this has a direct object *the column*, and two infinitives joined by *and*, *vibrate like a tubular drumhead* and *produce a tremendous crack*. These express what the column is made to do.

Of the remaining thirteen possibilities, the eight with *that makes* and *it makes* are unacceptable after a comma:

- *it makes*, and *that makes* if *that* is taken to be a demonstrative pronoun, would mark what follows as a new independent clauses. In this sort of formal discourse, a new independent clause requires a coordinating conjunction after a comma, so these would be unacceptable "comma splices".
- If *that* is not a demonstrative but a relative pronoun, it heads a relative clause marked by the preceding comma as non-restrictive; but relative *that* can only be used to introduce *restrictive* relative clauses, not non-restrictive ones.

In the three with *and making* we have to ask what the conjunction joins *making* to. It can't be joined to the two finite verbs *expands* and *contracts*, because it's a non-finite form, so it has to be joined to the preceding clause, and what follows the *and* has to be an independent clause. That would mean that *making the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead* has to be one of two things:

- It could be a participle clause modifying either the subject of the following independent clause or the independent clause itself. In either case, however, there is no entity present which could act as the subject of the independent clause; so that reading is excluded.
- It could be a gerund clause acting as the subject of the following clause, as in A) above. If that's the case, it requires a 3d-person singular finite form of *produce* as the verb for this clause. Neither *and produce* nor *and producing* qualifies, and we've already used *produces* in A). That leaves *is produced by*:

  > The nearby air rapidly expands and contracts, **and making** the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead **is produced by** a tremendous crack.

  That's grammatical; but it's wrong: a tremendous crack may "produce" an effect on hearers, but the vibration in the column is the cause, not the effect, of the sound.

That leaves only the remaining two pairs with *making*:

> The nearby air rapidly expands and contracts, **making** the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead **produces** a tremendous crack.
>
> The nearby air rapidly expands and contracts, **making** the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead **is produced by** a tremendous crack.

In both of these, *making the column vibrate like a tubular drumhead* can only be parsed as the subject of the independent clause; and once more, that would entail a comma splice. The second, moreover, even if it were pointed correctly, would be semantic nonsense.

Comment: Am I missing something here? OP's original text had **It makes** capitalized, from which I assume the presence/absence of relevant punctuation isn't a factor affecting the issue of which is the "correct answer". Some *permutations* of the available options are ungrammatical, but it seems to me every option *can* be grammatical when combined with compatible choices from other options. There is thus no meaningful answer to OP's specific question, which is *Why are **making + and producing** the correct choices?* It's like asking *Why is 3 the right answer to "Pick a number between 1 and 10"?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers But you can't ignore punctuation and capitalization in these types of questions. It would make the questions too complex.

Comment: How is "produces by a tremendous crack." grammatical? "Produces a tremendous crack" is certainly correct but with the "by" it's wrong.

Comment: @Catija Oops. Sorry, I got  confused cut-and-pasting the sentence and options over and over.

Comment: @Catija: Oh, silly me! Did I miss one? Actually I don't think I did. OP's set of options doesn't include *produces **by***

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's what I say. Of the 4x4= sixteen possibilities, three--the answer given by the book, and the two I start with--come out OK, and one is grammatically OK but semantic nonsense; the other twelve combinations don't work--ten of them because they involve comma splices which are not acceptable in the sort of writing represented here.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, there's dedication! But judging by his question text and comments, OP isn't actually asking which of the various permutations are valid. He appears to remain convinced only the *designated* answers are valid, and he wants us to explain *why*. But realistically, it's almost impossible to explain why one might choose *any* of the valid combinations over any other (though I've no doubt a case could be made for preferring certain combinations *in certain contexts*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Why* is almost certainly because (like so many test-composers) the author had a particular meaning in mind and failed to consider whether any of the "error" pairs might bear a construction which conveys a different but still grammatical meaning. It's a failure of imagination.

Comment: I know just making, and producing is correct as in mentioned in answer sheet.

Comment: @MojiMoji I've added a bit at the top explaining why the answer sheet version is correct. But it is **not** the **only** correct answer.

Comment: I read it more and more, to learn, please let me to get the point.